# How can i write better Code for the views.py

Tags: python, django

Good Morning,

i have a Question. I worked on my First Web-Application and now i finished the stuff and want to make the code a bit better. This Projekt is my Thesis Projekt too so they look into my Code and if thats too bad, ill get a bad Grade.

So there are only two Points on my list, for now, which are pretty important. 
At first, the Projekt is for Automate some Office Stuff like Create Google or Git Repos. So we have many API Calls and we have many Buttons on this Page. To delete the User, add him or whatever. We have more than user ofc, but i dont have to listen everything.

The Point now is, that i have a Tempplate where i have like 8 Buttons. Its a Management Panel where we can do tons of Actions. The Code for that is just ugly. 
Here is a small Example:

```
 if 'delete' in request.POST:

     todel = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
     deleteUser(request, todel, deleteOrArchive=0)

 if 'deactivate' in request.POST:

     todel = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
     deleteUser(request, todel, deleteOrArchive=1)
```

So there are many Ifs like that. I use Function Based Views everywhere because i thought its not that good to use Class Based Views here. I mean it would be the same if stuff here. 
So what i want is a suggestion, what can i do better here? Are there some opportunities to write better Code for this case? Because im really not happy with it and soon ill work on another Django Projekt and there i could use the knowledge too. I hope the Problem here is clear. The If Part is in every View. And i have many of them. Thanks in advance!

The Secod Problem:

I have many Requests to API's. Just normal API stuff. But i put the whole Response Body from, as an Example Git, in one Var and Loop the var to get the Informations. Is there another way to do it a bit better? It takes long until everything is finished so is there a way to make that better? Because there are Like 10k Lines in the Response Body and i just throw them into a Dic and loop them to save Data in Database and do some Actions with the Values. Maybe one of u guys had the same Problem and give me a small hint!

Thank you very much for reading this, maybe someone can help me here a bit! Maybe any experienced Django Devs?:D Would be very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use **views.py** for all of your functions. Taking this into account you opens up many possibilities for better organizing of your code.

Here's what I have done in certain cases:

1. Create a folder inside the specific django app where you will be creating several modules.

```
/django_app/
    /lib
    urls.py
    views.py
```

Inside the lib folder I added some files that will handle the various functions. And then in your **urls.py** you just need to import the files and point to those functions.

Example:

```
/lib/
    ManagePosts.py
    ManageProfiles.py
```

Urls.py

```
from .lib import ManagePosts, ManageProfiles


urlpatterns = [
    path('update_post', manage_posts.update),
    path('update_profile', manage_profiles.update)
]
```

Just making up examples here, hope I am helping. Regarding your second question: Could you provide some more examples of your API's

Answer (score 0):

**About the template with 8 buttons**, having many actions handled in one view is not uncommon.  To simplify your code, I see two options:

- Keep the numerous `if` in the view, and move the actions performed in each case in dedicated functions. This makes the view code shorter and easier to read:

  ```
  def delete(args):
      # lengthy stuff

  def deactivate(args):
      # other lengthy stuff

  def view(request):
      if 'delete' in request.POST:
          delete(args)
      elif 'deactivate' in request.POST:
          deactivate(args)
      return # ...
  ```
- Alternatively, you could have submit (POST) URLs that are different for each button.  That way, you can write one view for each type of action. Note that you can still use the same template for the different views if you want that the page displayed after posting data remains similar for all views. As a plus, with class-based views, common features between views can be shared using class inheritance.

By the way, in `todel = Employee.objects.get(id=id)`, since `id` seems to be data submitted by the client, you should not assume an object will necessarily match. This can cause 500 HTTP errors if you leave your code as is.

**Second question**

If I understand well, your responses return data corresponding to many objects. If that is the case, you could paginate results, that is display e.g. 10 results at a time. Django has [classes that make pagination easy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/paginator/). If you are writing an API, maybe using pagination provided by the [REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) would be good idea.